# What did the Buddha mean by "the stage beyond study" in the Shurangama Sutta?

Tags: sutras, stages-of-the-path

The Buddha mentioned, "The stage beyond study", in chapter 5 of the Shurangama Sutta.

What did the Buddha mean by this?

Comment: It's actually taken quite out of context so I'll try the add further information.

Comment: Is the version/translation of the sutta, which you're using, online?

Comment: I think you're referring to where it says, "stage beyond learning", in [this translation](http://www.cttbusa.org/shurangama/shurangama18.asp) -- `Then the World Honored One told all those in the assembly who were great Bodhisattvas and great Arhats, their outflows extinguished – “All of you Bodhisattvas and Arhats who are born from within my dharma and have attained the stage beyond learning, I now ask you: When you first brought forth your resolve and became enlightened to the eighteen realms, which one of these brought perfect penetration? Through which expedient did you enter samadhi?`

Comment: Yes, that's it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the word ASekkha. From Ven. Buddhadatta's [Pali-English dictionary](https://www.budsas.org/ebud/dict-pe/dictpe-01-a.htm):

> asekkha : one who does not require any further training. (m.) an Arahant.